# What is a suitable choice of Lyapunov function for this system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I have the following nonlinear system:

\begin{align}\dot x&=x(2-y^4) \\ \dot y &= -3x(1+y^3) \end{align}

I first verified this system using linearization; however, the eigenvalues are $\lambda =\pm i \sqrt{2} $ which is inconclusive for the stability of $(0,0)$. I tried to find a Lyapunov function to study its stability. I started with classical one $V(x,y) = a x^2 + b y^2$ by adjusting the coefficients $a,b$. However, it takes me hours but still no result. Any hints would be appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi from Vietnam

Comment: Chao ban nhe !!

Comment: Please elaborate on the eigenvalue, close to zero the system is essentially $\dot x=2x$, $\dot y=-3x$, which has eigenvalues $2$ and $0$.

Comment: Anh học đâu á ?

Comment: But then why you consider a system that is close to zero, even that the eigenvalues are 2 and 0, you cannot conclude anything about its stability since one of the eigenvalues are 0.

Comment: @haidangel Anh học PhD UWaterloo.

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously unstable; trajectories close to the eigendirection (2,-3) move away from the origin. Just look at the the [phase portrait](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot+%7Bx+%282+-+y%5E4%29%2C+-3+x+%281+%2B+y%5E3%29%7D%2C+x%3D-1..1%2C+y%3D-1..1). And if that isn't enough to make you believe it, you can first consider the system
$$
\dot x = 2-y^4
,\qquad
\dot y = -3(1+y^3)
,
$$
whose behaviour near the origin is very obvious (since now the origin is not an equilibrium), and then ponder what the effect of that extra factor of $\color{red}{x}$ in your system
$$
\dot x = \color{red}{x}(2-y^4)
,\qquad
\dot y = -3 \color{red}{x} (1+y^3)
$$
is.

Answer (score 1):

Why the point $(0, 0)$? You have a whole line of equilibria $x=0$, i.e. your whole $y-$axis is a set of equlibrium points. It is very hard to apply linaearization or Lyapunov techniques. The system however is integrable, i.e. there is a first integral, you ca cacluate by integrating
$$I(x, y) = x + \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{2-y^4}{1+y^3}\,dy$$ so you can try to use this as Lyapunov function. But to be clear, you should expect from this system to be unstable around any equilibrium point along $x = 0$.